# Does the speed at which a chain is pulled in vacuum of space, matter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vacuum, string, speed

If I pull a very long chain attached to a 50 pound dumbbell at $1000 \; mph$ in the vacuum of space (assuming we are uninfluenced by gravity), will the chain break? Take a steel chain for example. The chain is taut.

If the velocity isn't constant, will it still break?

Comment: Maybe, but we don't have enough details to give a definite answer. How strong is the chain? Is it loose or is it taut when we start pulling it? The speed is irrelevant, what matters is the acceleration.

Comment: The chain is taut. The chain is strong enough, for example, take a steel chain.

Comment: You should [edit] clarifying info like that into your question. OTOH, if the chain is strong enough, then it won't break, by definition. The strength of the steel won't be affected by being in a vacuum.

Comment: What about metals other than steel? Will they break? Are speed/acceleration a matter of concern here?

Comment: The vacuum of space has very little effect on most solids, but it can get very cold in space, and cold metals can become brittle. As I said earlier, speed is irrelevant. As mike stone said, acceleration determines the tension in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Since you pulling at a constant velocity, the dumbell is not accelerating. Consequently  the tension in the chain is zero. It will  not break therefore,

Comment: How do you know the chain wasn't stationary at $t=0$? It's not specified.

Comment: Because the OP says he is pulling at a *steady velocity* of 1000mph. His question is clearly directed at  the effect of *speed* not how it got there.

Comment: What if the velocity isn't constant? Will the chain break in the vaccum of space?

Comment: @AsgardianBrony You have to specify the initial conditions of your problem. What is $v(0)$ equal to ? what is the velocity at t =0

Comment: Let's consider V = 0 at t = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to me, If the chain is stationary at first and if apply enough force in a very short time, the impulse produced can break the chain. However if the chain is already moving with that mentioned amount of velocity (constant) it won't break.
If the force is increasing with time, it need to be a sudden increase in force to provide the needed impulse to break the chain.

Comment: Correct, but we do not know the initial conditions of the problem. V(0) = ???

Comment: Well I tried to consider all the circumstances I could think of conventionally.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this scenario.

Assume your chain and dumbbell are in orbit around the earth. Both are flying at about 7 km/s (about 16,000 mph), far faster than 1000 mph. If you pull ever so slightly on the chain, the dumbbell will start to move, without any appreciable stress on the chain.

It's not the speed at which they are flying that is important - the astronauts on the ISS do not feel their speed at all.

The important factor is the acceleration you impart to the dumbbell. As per Newton's second law, the greater the force, the greater the acceleration - and the reverse is also true: the greater the acceleration, the greater the force required. So, if you want to accelerate the dumbbell very quickly, you need to pull hard, and the chain may well break. If you want to accelerate very slowly, it won't.

The point at which it does break depends on the tensile strength of the chain, and without further details, that part pf your question cannot be answered.